# PCA as preprocessing for KNN model in caret not working

Tags: r, r-caret, data-preprocessing

I am executing a kNN classification with PCA as preprocessing (threshold = 0.8). However, when it seems to have concluded and I execute `varImp()` function, it does not give the importance of the Principal Components (as it should be doing). When I open the model fit information, the preProcess section is also NULL.

It seems as it is not doing the PCA.

The code for training control and training that I am using is:

```
 ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",                       
                     number = 10,                        
                     summaryFunction = defaultSummary,       
                     preProcOptions = list(thresh=0.8),
                     classProbs = TRUE
                     )

set.seed(150) 
knn.fit = train(defective~.,
                data = fTR,   
                method = "knn",
                preProcess = 'pca',
                tuneGrid = data.frame(k = 4),
                #tuneGrid = data.frame(k = seq(3,5,1)),
                #tuneLength = 10,
                trControl = ctrl, 
                metric = "Kappa")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: from [`?train`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-88/topics/train): Pre-processing code is only designed to work when x is a simple matrix or data frame. So it does not work with the formula S3 method.

Comment: Thanks @missuse . I just tried to train it with y and x dataframes, and tried executing the varImp() function again. It still does not work. I get the original variables' importance, not the PC's importances.

Comment: Knn does not have an associated varimp function. Rather it uses a general approach implemented in caret which is based on roc curves for classification and rmse for regression.. Could you try the same code with rf, do the original or transformed variables show up?

Comment: If you want to study the imapct of your varables on the knn model i suggest using permutation base importance for instance rather then the metod implmeneted in caret.

Comment: Hey @missuse , yes with 'rf' and 'nnet' as methods,  the transformed variables are the ones that show up with varImp(). Perfect, I'll have a look at permutation base. Thanks

Comment: Here is something to get you going https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/11/basic-xai-with-dalex%E2%80%8A-%E2%80%8Apart-2-permutation-based-variable-importance/